# Uniqueness of $y'=cos(y)$ solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle y'(x)=\cos\left(y(x)\right)\\
y(0)=0
\end{cases}
I've found explicitely $y$ and I know this equation has a unique solution. However is there a way to prove unicity of such an $y$ without using Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem ? I've tried to suppose two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ to show $y_1-y_2=0$. I only found
$$
(y_1-y_2)'=-2\sin\left(\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{y_1-y_2}{2}\right)
$$
But it did not help me. Can anyone got an idea to show it this way ?

Comment: If you set $z:=y_1-y_2$ and integrate what you found, using that $z(0)=0$, you should be able to conclude via [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) (integral form).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I wonder how you would use it ? Because $\cos\left(y\right)$ does satisfy $\leq y$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove the unicity in this particular case let $U$ be an open interval around $0\in{\mathbb R}$, where $|y(x)|<{\pi\over2}$, and consider the auxiliary function
$$u(x):=\log{1+\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)\over1-\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)}\qquad(x\in U)\ .\tag{1}$$
One computes
$$u'(x)=\left({1\over1+\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)}-{-1\over1-\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)}\right)\cos\bigl(y(x)\bigr)y'(x)\equiv2\qquad(x\in U)\ .$$
I think you will accept that this together with $u(0)=0$ implies $u(x)=2x$ for all $x\in U$. From $(1)$ we then get
$${1+\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)\over1-\sin\bigl(y(x)\bigr)}=e^{2x}\qquad(x\in U)\ ,$$
and this leads to
$$y(x)=\arcsin\bigl(\tanh x\bigr)\qquad(x\in U)\ .\tag{2}$$
As $|\tanh x|<1$ for all $x\in {\mathbb R}$ we see that the |RHS| of $(2)$ is $<{\pi\over2}$ for all $x\in{\mathbb R}$, so that we may choose $U={\mathbb R}$.

Comment: I found that $u'(x)=-sin(y(x))$